# Given $a^4+8b=4(a^3-1)-16\sqrt 3$ and $b^4+8a=4(b^3-1)+16\sqrt 3$, find $a^4+b^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $a^4+8b=4(a^3-1)-16\sqrt 3$ and $b^4+8a=4(b^3-1)+16\sqrt 3$, find $a^4+b^4$

I tried adding and subtracting both equations, but didn't get anywhere. Would appreciated any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I solved the two equations numerically, and the answers I got are $a\approx2.733$ and $b\approx-0.7311$. $a^4+b^4$ doesn't come out as anything special looking, it is $56.08$ at these values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Show us your effort.Please include all the details that you have already done. By the way,See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h497091p2791982)

Answer (score 6):

Adding both equation gives:
$$a^4+b^4+8(a+b)=4(a^3+b^3)-8$$
i.e: $$(a^2-2a)^2-4(a^2-2a)+b^4-4b^3+8b+8=0$$

Consider this equation is a quadratic equation with variable $a^2-2a$

So the discriminant is:$(-2)^2-(b^4-4b^3+8b+8)=-b^4+4b^3-8b-4=-(b^2-2b-2)^2$

Then:$b^2-2b-2=0$, so $b=1-\sqrt{3}$ or $b=1+\sqrt{3}$ then you can easily find $a=1+\sqrt{3}$ and $b=1-\sqrt{3}$ is only solution which is satisfied. Then $a^4+b^4=56$

Comment: It's not clear why the discriminant is zero. I think a better way is to get the expression as sum of two squares. The sum is zero only if each term is zero. You will get the same answer.

Comment: I assume $a,b$ are real numbers, then for existing of $a,b$ then the quadratic equation must have at least one root, but $-(b^2-2b-2)^2\le0$ then $-(b^2-2b-2)^2=0$. You can use your method, i use mine.

Comment: Indeed. That was the step that I've missed (even though I assume the same thing). +1

Comment: Exactly the same approach. See [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h497091p2791982)

Comment: In fact, your method is clearer, by splitting $8$ to $4+4$ and add them to both expressions to get $(a^2−2a-2)^2+(b^2−2b−2)^2=0$ which implies : $a^2−2a-2=0,b^2−2b−2=0$